# Why is the result of my GOOGLEFINANCE formula always the same?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I wrote a script with Apps Script for my Google Sheet, in order to have a record of stock prices at a given time. The script is executed every hour by a time-driven trigger.

```
function logStockPrices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var writeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Stock History');
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  writeSheet.appendRow([timestamp, '=googlefinance("NASDAQ:AAPL")', '=googlefinance("NYSE:SPCE")', '=googlefinance("FRA:D7G")', '=googlefinance("FRA:11L1")', '=googlefinance("FRA:LHA")', '=googlefinance("FRA:AIR")', '=googlefinance("FRA:10E")']);
}
```

But the price which is logged is always the same, even tho the price is changing.
The timestamp however is correct.

This is the link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11empPIZzVOc1tc7toTU6YVbeygVfaR_izW60QNYTjwI/edit?usp=sharing

I am thankful for any hint and comment.

Comment: Once a formula is pasted, you should copy/paste values only  preferably after a `.flush()` call

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet with the script to test it?

Comment: @ThaMaster, thanks for your comment! I am not sure if I understand you correctly. As I understand, the formula is inserted into the next cell from the next row, where it should then gather the information from the google finance server. I don't see what I should .flush() before inserting the data to the cell. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Kessy, Thanks for your comment. I attached a link to the spreadsheet in the initial question. The code is already in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sheet I can see that on each column the price is correct but for the last time that the price changed. So if yesterday one was 2€ and today it is 4€ you have all the column with 4€.

I would recommend you to get the current value on another cell and then copy that value, NOT the formula, and append to the last row the copied value.

To get a value from a cell you can do it bu getting the cell with [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) and then getting the result with [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).

Doing this for each finance you want to track you then will create a log with all the changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked doing it this way! But I am still wondering why it does not work the way I did it. Do you know why? Cause doing it this way looks pretty unhandy to me since you have to do it for every stock.